# shared asp.net object as static or cache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching, static

What is the best method of storing a shared object in asp.net? It will get called multiple times per request on every request. Ive been using these two methods but Id like to know if there is a better way. I refresh this object once an hour.

```
public static List<ResourceObject> SharedResources = new List<ResourceObject>()

//OR

public static List<ResourceObject> SharedResources
{
    get
    {
        List<ResourceObject> _sharedResources = HttpContext.Current.Cache["RedirectRoutes"] as List<ResourceObject>;
        if (_sharedResources == null)
        {
            _sharedResources = LoadNewSharedResource();
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["RedirectRoutes"] = _sharedResources;
        }

        return _redirectRoutes;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["RedirectRoutes"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both look reasonable enough, depending on your exact needs. But note that if anything is changing the returned `List<T>` (adding/removing elements etc) then you're going to potentially see problems. You'd be better off returning something like a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to prevent any mutations.

Comment: I actually leave out the 'set' normally. so, i think that prevents this problem.

Comment: Nope, a set would actually be ok since reference assignment is guaranteed atomic (in the case of the public field) and the ASP.NET `Cache` class is guaranteed to be threadsafe (in the case of the property). What I'm talking about is stuff like `SharedResources.Add(/* something */)`, `SharedResources.RemoveAt(0)` etc. These will potentially fail at run-time in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is changing frequently (i.e. hourly as you mentioned) then you'll be best to use the cache as it will be able to take care of flushing for you (assuming you pass the correct parameters when adding the value to the cache).  If you use a static value it will not be cleared out every hour automatically so you'd need to implement the check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If this is, as it seems, an object that needs to persist across requests, then this is a perfectly good and reasonable way to achieve it. You may want to put the cached version in a local variable if it is being accessed multiple times within one call, to save retrieving it from the cache each time.

Is there a specific issue with caching it like that that you are concerned about?

Comment: i was mostly concerned about using just a static object and not storing it in cache. I think i just needed the reassurance that what i was doing wasn't frowned on.

Comment: It don't get frowned on by me.