# Is it bad practice to use static fields to cache large objects in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, static-members

I've been reading up a lot lately on caching strategies for ASP.NET and my go-to method of using static fields as a cache store is never mentioned as an option. Is it a bad practice, and if so, why? Here's an example of how I would typically use it:

```
public static Class Repository {
    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    private static List<Products> _products = null;
    public static void GetProducts() {
        if (_products != null) { return _products; }
        lock(_lockObject) {
            _products = DAL.LoadProducts()
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

The reason I prefer this pattern to say, System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is because it uses no serialization and therefore scales to large objects; I have used it successfully to cache very large collections of objects from entire database tables which I then query using LINQ instead of querying the DB with SQL, resulting in massive performance gains. This pattern has served me well over a number of projects in scenarios where:

1. I want to cache large data sets that are expensive to retrieve from storage
2. The data will be cached for a period of hours or days and staleness is not a concern.
3. The data be used frequently, but often uniquely filtered or transformed for a specific request.
4. The volume of data is comfortably within the memory capacity of the host server.

Since I find this pattern so useful, I'm curious as to why the various books and tutorials on the subject don't even really discuss it as an option.

Comment: "prefer this pattern to say, System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is because it uses no serialization"? Very strange reason as `MemoryCache` does not use serialization...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624905/shared-asp-net-object-as-static-or-cache

Comment: In short yes, is bad idea and bad practice. The reason is that static objects never "die" so you will create memory leaks.

Comment: @JorgeCode: this wouldn't matter if the object truly will be used throughout the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @JorgeCode - you have very strange definition of "memory leak" I guess. How it is "memory leak" if object is *expected* to be available for lifetime of process?

Comment: @wwarby: note that it requires locking, hence requires thinking about multithreading, and most beginner and intermediate books stay far away from multithreading.

Comment: Sounds like you are misinterpreting how [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) works - the name is a bit of a hint.

Comment: I see you use `lock` that means you use threads. In general when you use the database you should use it and dispose the connection, if not the connection will stay open and after a while your app will crash. With threads it's almost certain that you'll have unpredictable code. If you have the opportunity use `Async` and `Tasks` (framework > 4.0). Also you violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Your solution is OK, I'm assuming you have some mechanism for invalidating the cache when the underlying data changes as well ? Also I think your test *if (_products != null)* should also be inside the critical region, no ?

Comment: @JorgeCode - As others have mentioned, in these scenarios I very much do intend for the objects to live for the duration of the process. I do periodically expire them and recreate them from source, but the intended behaviour is once that memory is consumed, it stays that way.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Good point, one one of the obvious downsides of my approach. I have sometimes forgotten to lock the object and created race conditions where two or more clients try to create these massive cached object graphs at the same time. Seems I would still have that problem with MemoryCache though, if my intention is to prevent hitting the source twice and not just to avoid a collision in writing to the cache.

Comment: @JorgeCode - on your point about the single responsibility principal, in practice I typically use a separate static class to manage the cache, I just put it all in one class in the simplified example in this post.

Comment: @JorgeCode - on the issue of locks, I'm not creating any threads myself, but I'm under the (perhaps incorrect) impression that if two users request the same URL at the same time from my site, they effectively compete to write to that static field on separate threads. That seems to be my experience in practice, and as such, async/await wouldn't necessarily help me escape that race condition. Have I got that all wrong?

Comment: @wwarby in short yes. You shouldn't do that. It's all a matter of design. If you haven't this static field would not be necessary to use `locks` or whatever... It's simple. You call the db from IoC container who's then call a repository and finally dispose the object (and close the db connection). With every call to db it's been created new connection so it's not necessary to use `lock`. This will be handled by the db automatically. Ah... and what you want to use it's called transactions and it's implemented in other way...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but there is a simple solution to the issue of two threads doing the same work when encountering some unpopulated data cache.

```
public static class Repository<T>
{
    private static readonly object LockSemaphore = new object();
    private static T _dataYouWantCached;

    public static void ReadData()
    {
        if (_dataYouWantCached != null)
        {
            return _dataYouWantCached;
        }

        lock (LockSemaphore)
        {
            //This second check will prevent the "next" thread from requerying the same data that
            //the first thread populated.
            if (_dataYouWantCached != null)
                return _dataYouWantCached;

            _dataYouWantCached = SomeStaticDataAccess.LoadData();

            return _dataYouWantCached;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that your understanding of MemoryCache is wrong, and it takes less code to store something in the MemoryCache reliably than it does a static, I don't see why you would insist on using a pattern that is error prone, leaky, and more difficult to use...

In any event, there are times when using a static to cache something is appropriate.  But, in general, you should initialize statics and never change them during the life of the process.  As soon as you start playing with stuff is where you will start to get pain.

Comment: There's no need for that kind of derisive reply. I've taken the time to come here and ask whether my pattern IS the hard way. Clearly I did have a misconception about how MemoryCache works and as such it probably is the better solution, but my code is not leaky in the normal sense of the term - it holds data in memory for the lifetime of the process, which is exactly my intention, and if the pattern is error prone, it has yet to cause me any such problems.

Comment: @wwarby - I was making a point, it seems that many people find some technique and use it over the years, despite the emergence of better ones, and they insist on staying with the old method.  This is insisting on doing things the hard way (even though you know about the new).  In any event, you have a flaw in your code.. there is a race condition if two people access your code for the first time, they both may see _prodcts as null and both allocate a new Products().  In this case, it's probably not a big deal, just 2x the queries, but in other cases it could be more critical.

Comment: Although there could be a critical problem here, one thread may get a different object than the second thread if they both allocated new Products, and if your code does any object comparisons it could create duplicates or cause other issues if it assumes they will be the same object.